Date and Time Capture formatting
I have Problem there when i code at power apps (Image 1) and i want to capture to my sharepoint list in (image 2).
But then the capturing format is wrong and i have input code for sharepoint list is at (image 3).
Can someone help me whether my code in (image 1) is Wrong.
Please do help me.
Thank in advance.
Power Fx expression:

SharePoint list:

Schema:

I was expect for the format is (hh:mm dd-mm-yyyy)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please refer to this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288156/how-to-format-tolocaledatestringmydatetimecolumn-to-return-yyyy-mm-dd

Is the type of the column SharePoint Text or Date+Time? If the former, then you can update the expression in Power Apps to send the date in the format you want:
Set(
  varNewItem,
  Patch(
    list_name_with_email,
    LookUp(list_name_with_email, Email = User().Email),
    {
      Date_Start:
        Text(
          DatePicker3_2.SelectedDate + Time(Value(Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value), Value(Dropdown2_3.Selected.Value), 0),
          "hh:mm dd-mm-yyyy"
        )
    }
  )
)

If the latter (the column is a date/time column in SharePoint), then you will need to head to SharePoint to format the view of the column accordingly, using the time before the date in your schema, as shown below
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=toLocaleTimeString(@currentField) + ' ' + toLocaleDateString(@currentField)"
}

